# Automate app_localizations.dart generation

Tags: flutter, internationalization, locale

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to make my app supporting string internationalization in a smooth way. I've found out from flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) that the standard way is to use `flutter_localizations` library.
Everything works quite fine but every time I add a new string to `.arb` files and I try to use that string in the codebase I get a compilation error and I have to manually import app_localizations package `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'` in each source code file.
When I launch the app the compilation error vanishes and everything works fine, but the compilation error is quite annoying.

[image]

Is there any way to automate the regeneration of `app_localizations.dart` when a new string is inserted in language files?

Comment: it happens to me too also , you have just to reload your app and it will disappear

Comment: yeah also In my case to when I reload the app it disappears, but it's quite annoying :(

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` command?

Comment: @YagneshLashkari doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: invalidating cache in android studio made the red indicators go away. but it's a hassle to keep on doing this. flutter clean didnt work either